# Load a PNG image from a USB stick with stb_image

Tags: c, png, freertos, stb-image

I'm asking here because the documentation concerning the aforementioned library is horribly lacking. As written in the title, I want to load a PNG image from a USB stick and then decode it using `stb_image` but I don't know how to go about it.

To add a bit of context, I'm using a discovery board from ST, the **STM32F769I** and running FreeRTOS.

I thought first that simply calling `"stbi_load"` with the full path `("0:MYIMAGE.PNG")` would suffice but it doesn't.

Therefore, I suppose another function must be used for that purpose but which one ? `stbi_load_from_memory` ? I don't have it very clear. Or should I first call a FatFS function like  `f_open()` before being able to call any decoding function?

Any help is more than appreciated. It'd be very helpful if you could write here a simple example that does the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to give us more context. Right now it kind of sounds like you're developing for an embedded system, possibly without an operating system. If that's true, then edit your question to include that information (and if not, then edit your question to tell us *that*). And maybe take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There a several search engine results for "stbi_load" which might be helpful for you to follow up, including some Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: I guess that if I had found an answer online, I wouldn't have posted a question here, no?